# .NET 5 Blazor Server App ObjectResult "Accept" header not being respected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm creating a controller in a .NET 5 Blazor Server App, and the `OkObjectResult` I'm returning from my controller is always returning JSON, even when I set `Accepts: application/xml`.

Due to getting the correct result inside my custom `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`, I tend to think this might be a bug.

Startup.cs:

```
services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
    })
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, ModelStateEntry> firstModelErrorPropertyName = actionContext.ModelState.First(s => s.Value.Errors.Count > 0);
            ModelError firstError = firstModelErrorPropertyName.Value.Errors.First();
            ObjectResult toReturn = new ObjectResult(new ErrorResponse
            {
                Status = RequestStatus.Fail,
                ErrorCode = ErrorCode.MissingParameter,
                ErrorDescription = $"Missing POST parameter: {firstModelErrorPropertyName.Key}: {"Description here"}"
            });

            toReturn.StatusCode = 200;

            return toReturn;
        };
    })
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlOptions(options =>
    {
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumMemberConverter());
    });
```

Controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enroll a member in IDCS services.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost("enroll")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[FormatFilter]
public async Task<IActionResult> EnrollAsync(
     [FromForm] EnrollRequest req)
{
    return Ok(new
    {
        content = "Enroll"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue right after posting. If I return a defined object:

```
return Ok(new EnrollmentSuccessResponse
    {
        Content = "Enroll"
    });
```

instead of an anonymous object

```
return Ok(new
    {
        content = "Enroll"
    });
```

Everything works as expected.